# manually move to mobile home and recent buttons in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

I'm developing online test application using flutter for that i'm trying to block all the back, recent and home button. I have detected the pressing of recent and home button. Issue in that is when i press the home button or recent button directly minimize my app. Is there any possibilities to detect key press home button or recent button.

If possible provide the solution. I have attached the photo for your reference

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAR4a.jpg]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Back button can be disabled using `WillPopScope` widget, I also think that the home button can't be disabled but can keep track of them using [hardware_buttons](https://pub.dev/packages/hardware_buttons) package.

Comment: hardware_buttons is deprecated now.. Is any other possibilities